# How to fix this datetime iso format error in django-python which is occuring since I upgraded my python to 3.7

Tags: python, django, datetime, django-models, datetime-format

This is the error that I am facing when I try to run migrate or runserver or any command. Please Help.

```py
"raise ValueError(f'Invalid isoformat string: {date_string!r}')"
```

I am facing this error since I upgraded my python to version 3.7.

```py
Models.py:


from django.db import models
from datetime import datetime

# Create your models here.
class Posts(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    body = models.TextField()
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now, blank=True)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "Posts"
```

[Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qH7zY.png) [Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uu9FT.png)

Comment: What if you specify `default=datetime.now` so *without* the brackets, and *without* `.fromisoformat()`.

Comment: Still not working

Comment: Seems duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/127803/how-do-i-parse-an-iso-8601-formatted-date?rq=1

Answer (score -1):

Issue Solved there was environment path error.